# Pyspark - Partial text look up and create column for the new value

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-cleaning

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.
df1 looks like this

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd |
| 2 | abc |
| 3 | def |
| 4 | hijk |
| 5 | hij |
| 6 | hi |
| 7 | lmno |
| 8 | lmn |
| 9 | pqrst |
| 10 | pq |

and df2 looks like this.

| Value |
| --- |
| abcd |
| hijk |
| lmno |

I need to have a partial lookup for the df2 dataframe values and create different rows based on the number of matches from the df1 by reducing the length from the last. So my resulting df would look like this.

| Value | id1 | len(value)-1 | id2 | len(value)-2 | id3 | len(value)-3 | id4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 1 | abc | 2 | ab | null | a | null |
| hijk | 4 | hij | 5 | hi | 6 | h | null |
| lmno | 7 | lmn | 8 | lm | null | l | null |